# Операции над циклом range

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите найти ошибку.
Из предложенного списка нужно убрать те числа, которые нарушают последовательность. Но из-за указанного range для сравнения рядом стоящих пар, последнее значение списка не выводится. Есть ли у вас идеи, как можно исправить код?

```
def ranges(number):
    list = []
    for i in range(len(number)-1):
        
        if number[i]<number[i+1]:
            list.append(number[i])
       
    return (list) 

print(ranges([7, 2, 4, 7, 16, 8, 10, 12]))
```

Comment: Вам нужно пройтись по списку и оставить только те элементы, которые образуют возрастающую последовательность?

Comment: Да, но сделать хочу именно через range, без sorted, но в range всегда не входит последнее значение

Comment: Хотелось бы понять, почему из первой пары было выкинуто именно `7`, а не `2`? Описание задачи не очень чёткое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас проблема не в диапазоне range, последний элемент не попадает в результирующий список из-за того, что для него "нет пары", а ваш цикл перебирает именно все пары соседних элементов. Если отталкиваться от вашего решения, то достаточно сделать дополнительную проверку: не нарушает ли последний элемент общую последовательность.

```
def ranges(numbers):
    result_numbers = []
    for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i - 1] < numbers[i]:
            result_numbers.append(numbers[i - 1])
    if numbers[-1] > numbers[-2]:
        result_numbers.append(numbers[-1])
    return result_numbers

print(ranges([7, 2, 4, 7, 16, 8, 10, 12])) # [2, 4, 7, 8, 10, 12]
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: Так ваш код выдаёт точно такой же результат, как и код в вопросе.

Comment: @CrazyElf прошу прощения, поспешил, сейчас отредактирую.

Answer (score 1):

Не называйте свою переменную `list`, так вы перекрываете встроенный класс `list`. А чтобы последнее число списка попало в результат нужно проверять этот случай отдельно. Либо после окончания цикла (но тогда придётся повторять там проверку на "меньше"), либо вставить проверку на то, что это последний элемент внутрь вашей проверки, чтобы кода получилось поменьше (но для больших списков это будет неэффективно):

```
def ranges(number):
    lst = []
    for i in range(len(number)-1):
        
        if number[i]<number[i+1]:
            lst.append(number[i])
            # Проверка, что это был последний элемент
            # Если да, то его тоже добавляем - условие то выполнено
            if i == len(number)-2:
                lst.append(number[i+1])
       
    return (lst) 

print(ranges([7, 2, 4, 7, 16, 8, 10, 12]))
```

Вывод:

```
[2, 4, 7, 8, 10, 12]
```